# FirebaseInstallationsException on latest version

Tags: android, firebase, responsys

Every time I update my app's Firebase dependencies to anything more recent than the Feb. 27 2020 update, I start seeing this exception when I run my app:

```
04-29 18:21:58.170  3314  3541 E Firebase-Installations: Firebase Installations can not communicate with Firebase server APIs due to invalid configuration. Please update your Firebase initialization process and set valid Firebase options (API key, Project ID, Application ID) when initializing Firebase.
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to get FIS auth token
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.zzb(Unknown Source:61)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.Tasks.await(Unknown Source:23)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzt.zzb(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.6:54)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzt.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@@20.1.6:72)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at com.google.firebase.iid.zzs.run(Unknown Source:12)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at com.google.android.gms.common.util.concurrent.zza.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.1.1:6)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId: Caused by: com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallationsException
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.doNetworkCall(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.2.2:350)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations.lambda$doRegistrationInternal$0(com.google.firebase:firebase-installations@@16.2.2:323)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at com.google.firebase.installations.FirebaseInstallations$$Lambda$5.run(Unknown Source:4)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
04-29 18:21:58.177  3314  3543 E FirebaseInstanceId:    ... 1 more
```

I've read several related questions and tried all of the following:

1. I verified my API key has no restrictions (SHA-1 or API restrictions) in Google Cloud Platform.
2. I verified the google-services.json provided by Firebase matches the one included in my project.
3. I verified the API key, project ID, and application ID in the google-services.json file are correct.
4. I verified all the devices I'm testing on (a mix of emulators with different API versions and physical devices) have the Play Store and Play Services and are updated to the latest versions.
5. I verified the APK is signed with the correct key - debug key for debug builds and my app signing key for release builds.
6. I verified Firebase is set up correctly in my app.

Here's the relevant parts of the project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.72'

    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.28.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
}
```

And the app's build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        // ...
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            // ...
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:19.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['PushIOManager-6.44.aar'])
    // etc...
}
```

I left out the bundles, flavors, other dependencies, etc. but hopefully this is enough. I did have this in my Application class's onCreate method:

```
// Initialize Fabric with Crashlytics
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

// Initialize Firebase
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

I took those out because I believe they're no longer needed. Regardless, it makes no difference. I've gone over the Firebase documentation several times and can't figure out what I'm missing.

Edit: one of the dependencies I originally left out was Responsys. As soon as I removed it from my app, I stopped seeing the errors. I'm waiting to hear back from their support team.

Answer (score 4):

#### Background

Unfortunately, Google's frontend might incorrectly identify your API key as invalid. This can happen if your API key has not been used in a long time.

`FirebaseInstallations` is new infrastructure for Firebase services that makes use of the API key that you initialize Firebase with. If you recently updated your Firebase SDKs, `FirebaseInstallations` might have started using your API key which was not used before.

---

#### Remedy

If you have issues with your API key, you can create a new API key in the Cloud Console:

- go to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?folder)
- choose the relevant project (i.e. the project you use for your application)
- open the menu and go to `APIs & Services` → `Credentials`
- on top of the page click on `+ CREATE CREDENTIALS` → `API key`
- replace the API key in your application with the newly created API key

---

#### google-services.json

In case you are using the `google-services.json` config file from your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/), you first have to delete or restrict the API key used in your current `google-services.json` in order to make Firebase update config file and use a new API key.

- Identify the API key in your `google-services.json` config file.
- Confirm that the API key is creating the erroneous requests by checking its usage against the [Firebase Installations API metrics page](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/credentials). The column `Usage with this service` of your API key should show a number greater than 0.
- Delete that API key by clicking the bin symbol or add `Application restrictions` to that API key by clicking the pencil symbol. **!!Warning!!** Do not delete an API key that existing installations of your applications require for other Firebase services like Firebase Auth or Realtime-Database.

Wait a couple of minutes for Google servers to update. The next download of your `google-service.json` config file should contain a new API key.

---

#### Links

Other relevant links regarding API keys and the [Firebase Installations API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com):

- https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/init-options
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/blob/master/firebase-installations/API_KEY_RESTRICTIONS.md
- https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2020-02-27

Answer (score 3):

For me, all provided solutions didn't work: I upgraded all dependencies, imported a new google-services.json which was exactly the same. I had no API restrictions in the https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/ . Downgrading was not an options because of other dependencies.

What solved it for me was to set the Key restrictions in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/ to "None".

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase installation services (a new component used by Firebase Cloud Messaging) requires a valid Firebase combination options (specifically API key, Project ID, Application ID). Your app seems to have gotten an invalid combination along the way.

If you're initializing the app from a `google-services.json`, download the latest version of that file for the app from the Firebase console, and re-include it in your project. Manually verifying the contents of this file is error prone, so I'd just make a backup copy of the current file and replace it with the one you downloaded.

If that doesn't solve the problem, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) with the `google-services.json` and other information for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: I'm sure I have the correct google-services.json file because it worked fine before the Feb update. I've downloaded it and manually verified the values several times.

Comment: The fact that the file worked before is not the point here, as this new library introduces some new checks. If you're not willing to take my troubleshooting guidance and try it, there's not a lot more I can do to help though. In that case, it'd be best to reach out to support (although I wouldn't be surprised if they give the same first step about updating your `google-services.json`).

Comment: I didn't ignore your guidance. After you answered, I did download the file again and make sure it was correct. I also verified the values in values.xml (under the generated build folder) are correct.

Comment: In that case it's best to reach out to support through the link I gave, as they can look at your project and possibly see what's going wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

1. If You are using a `Real device` Check your Internet connection.
2. If you are using android studio `Emulator` - Establish an internet connection by resetting the emulator.

   2.1. Open `Tools -> AVD manager`

[image: Step 2.1]

2.2. Wipe Data of the emulator
[image: Wipe Data of the emulator 2.2]

3. Run Project using fresh emulator.